# Tooltip Bottom Positioning

Tags: html, css, position, tooltip

I'm a guitar player, not a coder, but I have a guitar lesson site I'm trying to upgrade. (Sorry if I screw up posting the code below.) I have a tooltip positioning problem that uses HTML and CSS. I wonder if anyone can help. If you roll over it on this page, you'll see what I'm wanting it to do. (It also needs to work on mobile touchscreens.) Thanks.
https://codepen.io/Daverino/pen/zboNoQ

```css
    .toolTipDiv {
      float: none;
      width: 275px;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .toolTipLink a {
      display: block;
      color: #202020;
      background-color: transparent;
      width: auto;
      padding: 0px 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-bottom-color: #878787;
      line-height: 17px;
    }
    
    .toolTipLink a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: #9B0E11;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    a.tooltip span {
      z-index: 10;
      display: none;
      padding: 7px 10px;
      margin-top: -80px;
      /* this doesn't do anything:
      margin-bottom: [any value]px;
      */
      margin-left: 200px;
      width: 140px;
      line-height: 16px;
      opacity: 0.85;
    }
    
    a.tooltip:hover span {
      display: inline;
      position: absolute;
      color: #EEE;
      background: #000;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
    
    <div class="toolTipDiv">
    
    <span class="toolTipLink"> 
    
    <a href=“#” class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltipWrapper">
    <div class="toolTipEdge">Medium amount of text in this line.</div>
    <span>I want the bottom of every tooltip to be at the top of every line it hovers over.</span>
    </div>
    </a> 
    
    <a href=“#” class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltipWrapper">
    <div class="toolTipEdge">This is the text that will be hovered over. Sometimes it may be this long</div>
    <span>The bottom of this tooltip is too low. It should be just above the line.</span>
    </div>
    </a> 
    
    <a href=“#” class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltipWrapper">
    <div class="toolTipEdge">Here is a shorter line of text.</div>
    <span>Sometimes the text in the "tooltip" will be a couple sentences long. If the tooltip text is ong or if it is short, the bottom of the tooltip should be right above the hovered line.</span>
    </div>
    </a> 
    
    <a href=“#” class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltipWrapper">
    <div class="toolTipEdge">Medium amount of text in this line.</div>
    <span>This tooltip is way too high.</span>
    </div>
    </a> 
    
    </span> 
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Where you want to position the Tooltip at the top or bottom ?

Answer (score 0):

For "span", you said it was absolute, but didn't give any positioning information.  In this case add "bottom":

```
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0em;
```

There also isn't anything for it to be relative to, so add:

```
   .tooltipWrapper { position: relative; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out [Tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) its a cool tooltip and popover library, it's highly customizable.

Answer (score 0):

A guy at a Facebook group called HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT wrote a codepen that fixed it. Apparently I'd messed up the absolute and relative positioning.
https://codepen.io/jkarkosza/pen/WmopbP

```
    .toolTipDiv {
    float: none;
    width: 275px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.toolTipLink a {
display: block;
color: #202020;
background-color: transparent;
width: auto;
padding: 0px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12px;
margin-left: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #878787;
line-height: 17px;
}

.toolTipLink a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: #9B0E11;
padding-left: 10px;
}

a.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

a.tooltip span {
z-index: 10;
display: none;
padding: 7px 10px;
position:absolute; 
bottom: 100%;
color:#EEE;
background:#000;
/* margin-left: 200px; */
width: 140px;
line-height: 16px;
opacity: 0.85;
}

a.tooltip:hover span{
display:block;
}

<body>

<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="toolTipDiv">

<span class="toolTipLink"> 

<a href="_lessons/_beginner/054-Basic-Boogie-Rock.html" target="_blank" class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltipWrapper">
<div class="toolTipEdge">Medium amount of text in this line.</div>
<span>I want the bottom of every tooltip to be at the top of every line it hovers over.</span>
</div>
</a> 

<a href="_lessons/_beginner/054-Basic-Boogie-Rock.html" target="_blank" class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltipWrapper">
<div class="toolTipEdge">This is the text that will be hovered over. Sometimes it may be this long</div>
<span>The bottom of this tooltip is too low. It should be just above the line.</span>
</div>
</a> 

<a href="_lessons/_beginner/054-Basic-Boogie-Rock.html" target="_blank" class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltipWrapper">
<div class="toolTipEdge">Here is a shorter line of text.</div>
<span>Sometimes the text in the "tooltip" will be a couple sentences long. If the tooltip text is ong or if it is short, the bottom of the tooltip should be right above the hovered line.</span>
</div>
</a> 

<a href="_lessons/_beginner/054-Basic-Boogie-Rock.html" target="_blank" class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltipWrapper">
<div class="toolTipEdge">Medium amount of text in this line.</div>
<span>This tooltip is way too high.</span>
</div>
</a> 

</span> 
</div>

</body>
```